# Why say "exists smooth structure" instead of "is a smooth manifold"?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

As some of you know I started to learn differential geometry some weeks ago. Now I came across this theorem (you can find it in Lee's Intro to Smooth Manifolds but it is in many other books also:

Suppose $E$ is a connected smooth manifold and $\Gamma$ is a discrete Lie group acting smoothly, freely, and properly on $E$. Then the orbit space $E/\Gamma$ is a topological manifold and has a unique smooth structure such that $\pi:E \to E/\Gamma$ is a smooth normal covering map.

I have two questions about this theorem. One is:

> If there is a smooth structure on $E/\Gamma$ wouldn't this make
>   $E/\Gamma$ a smooth manifold? So why not write something like "Then
>   the orbit space $E/\Gamma$ is a smooth manifold and..."?

It is not clear to me whether one could rephrase it like this because I'm sure there is a good reason why the author chose the wording and perhaps $E/\Gamma$ is indeed not a smooth manifold at all.

The other thing that I don't understand is:

> Why does $\Gamma$ have to be a Lie group? Could one not replace it
>   with any discrete group that acts smoothly freely and properly?

Comment: For the first statement, the author is saying that there is a unique smooth structure on $E/\Gamma$ such that $\pi:E \to E/\Gamma$ is smooth. (Cf. the topology on a quotient topological space). In general, even "nice" manifolds (say, a finite CW-complex) may have many, one, or no possible smooth structures. There may be other smooth structures on $E/\Gamma$, but they wouldn't make the quotient map smooth.

Comment: For the second statement, see Theorem 9.19 in Lee's text.

Comment: @anomaly But having a smooth structure does make it a smooth manifold. Or does it not?

Comment: A smooth manifold is a manifold with a particular choice of smooth structure.

Comment: This is the difference between "There exists one" and "we have chosen a specific one".